Github App refreshable access token doesn't auto renews for Teamcity VCS connection Authentication
Recently we configured out Teamcity VCS root connection setting for Github repositories and utilized Github app for the authentication setting in VCS connections by selecting:
Authentication method as Refreshable access token via Github app(oauth2).
After few months(we are assuming 6 month) while one of the teamcity build pipeline failed with error as: not authorized.
We had to manually navigate to the VCS root connection setting of the pipeline and click on Acquire new button against Token field , and then it started working.

Is it expected that we do it every 6 month? Shouldn't it re-new the refreshable access token automatically ? If not, is there a way to have it rotated automatically via github app itself ?
Note: Our github app setting have User-to-server token expiration enabled from the optional features.
